# google map route with through specified locations?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

i want google map route like google map directions with my specified locations.
now google map internally calculating the shortest path and showing the route, but i want give locations to the path, so that the route must pass through the specified locations.

any idea, how GDirections with waypoints work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use [waypoints](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Waypoints)

[working sample](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints.html)

```
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

function initialize() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 6,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: chicago
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
}

function calcRoute() {
  var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
  var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
  var waypts = [];
  var checkboxArray = document.getElementById("waypoints");
  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxArray.length; i++) {
    if (checkboxArray.options[i].selected == true) {
      waypts.push({
          location:checkboxArray[i].value,
          stopover:true
      });
    }
  }

  var request = {
      origin: start,
      destination: end,
      waypoints: waypts,
      optimizeWaypoints: true,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      var route = response.routes[0];
      var summaryPanel = document.getElementById("directions_panel");
      summaryPanel.innerHTML = "";
      // For each route, display summary information.
      for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
        var routeSegment = i+1;
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += "<b>Route Segment: " + routeSegment + "</b><br />";
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].start_address + " to ";
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].end_address + "<br />";
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].distance.text + "<br /><br />";
      }
    }
  });
}
```